# MVC4: Two radio buttons for a single boolean model property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, radiobuttonfor

I'm attempting to find the correct Razor syntax for mutually exclusive radio buttons that both reflect the value of a boolean property on my model.  My model has this:

```
public bool IsFemale{ get; set; }
```

I would like to display this with two radio buttons, one "Male" and the other "Female," but everything I've tried so far has not reflected the actual value of the `IsFemale` property on the model.  Currently, I have this:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale, !Model.IsFemale) Male
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale, Model.IsFemale) Female
```

This seems to persist the value correctly if I change and update, but does not mark the correct value as checked.  I'm sure this is something stupid, but I'm stuck.

Comment: What is your app's culture? Are you using localized .net? Because I cannot repro your issue and because Darin's solution worked maybe this is some culture setting issue...

Comment: I'm not currently setting the culture, so I assume it's using the machine default.

Comment: Interesting... It's just strange because I'd also expect it work as you tried in fact it does in my repro...

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale, "false") Male
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale, "true") Female
```

And here's the full code:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool IsFemale { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel
        {
            IsFemale = true
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return Content("IsFemale: " + model.IsFemale);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale, "false", new { id = "male" }) 
    @Html.Label("male", "Male")

    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale, "true", new { id = "female" })
    @Html.Label("female", "Female")
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Comment: Yep, that works.  That seems completely counter-intuitive to me, since the overload for `RadioButtonFor` specifies that parameter as `object value`.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Great Answer. Works for Label clicking too.

Comment: in my case default is false and if i dont click radio to change then on submit i receive true.

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsWorkDefaultAddress, "true", new { id = "default-work" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsWorkDefaultAddress, "false", new { id = "default-home" })

Comment: If you want neither radio button selected then make IsFemale the nullable "bool?" and set IsFemale = null.

Comment: Why is a real bool value like `@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale, false, new { id = "male" }) ` not working?

Answer (score 14):

In MVC 6 (ASP.NET Core) this can also be achieved with tag helpers:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" asp-for="IsFemale" value="false" /> Male
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" asp-for="IsFemale" value="true" /> Female
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as September 2022.

Boolean radio button using: .NET Framework 4.7.2, MVC 5.2.7, Bootstrap 5.1.3.

## Model

```cs
public class TheViewModel
{
    public bool IndustrialDegree { get; set; }
}
```

## View

```
<div class="col-4 col-md-2 mb-3">
    @Html.Label("Industrial Degree", new { @class = "d-block form-label" })
    <div class="btn-group d-flex" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.IndustrialDegree, true, new { @class = "btn-check", @id = "IndustrialDegreeTrue" })
        @Html.Label("IndustrialDegreeTrue", "Yes", new { @class = "btn btn-outline-primary" })

        @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.IndustrialDegree, false, new { @class = "btn-check", @id = "IndustrialDegreeFalse" })
        @Html.Label("IndustrialDegreeFalse", "No", new { @class = "btn btn-outline-primary" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that I'm returning a pure boolean value to the controller.

## Result

[image: Radio button, using boolean values]

It works in both directions.

This is what you'll see on the controller when debugging the view model.

[image: false] and [image: true]