# @Html.RadioButtonFor asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to add two radiobuttons in my feedback form
[image]

```
<input type="radio" id="startNowYes" value="true" name="startNow" checked="checked"> Yes
<input type="radio" id="startNowNo" value="false" name="startNow"> No
```

I added in my model

```
namespace CorePartners_Site2.Models
{
public class CareerForm
{
    //...
    public StartNow Start { get; set; }                                                    
 }

public enum StartNow
{
    Yes,
    No
}
}
```

but can someone explain me how to add radiobuttons in my view? I cant understand.

Comment: You can not set enum values. there are readonly types.

Comment: Can I use List for my radiobuttons?

Comment: Find your answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518352/mvc4-two-radio-buttons-for-a-single-boolean-model-property

Comment: @MohamedFarrag, suggestion is the better solution for this scenerio. (From my perspective the best way because of darinDimitrov's suggestion :) )

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the model in you view  CareerForm  and implement a toString method or getter to return a string value or boolean value and 
then you need to access the StartNow.Yes on normal HTMl radio button value like:

```
<input type="radio" id="startNowYes" value="{Model.StartNow.Yes} name="startNow"               checked="checked"> Yes


<input type="radio" id="startNowNo" value="{Model.StartNow.No} name="startNow" checked="checked"> No
```

Comment: Yes, I imported the model in you view `@model CorePartners_Site2.Models.CareerForm`, but I dont undertand what should I do then?