# MVC: 404 error, ViewModel not found

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC and getting this depressing error when I try to insert buttons into a table.

I have for my .cshtml ViewModel in EditorTemplates:

```
@model EditorForSample.Models.ProductViewModel


<tr>
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Selected)</td>
    <td colspan="1">
        @Model.Name
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.Password
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Password)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(e => e.Locked, true)</td>
    <td>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(e => e.Locked, false)</td>
</tr>
```

And for the model:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public bool Selected{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
 public bool Locked { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting a 404 error in the .cshtml even though I cannot determine why the syntax is wrong.

Edit: Okay, it turns out that the above actually does work when I manually change the URL and instead my problem is one of the routing randomly changing of its own accord and trying to redirect to the model view CSHTML.

Comment: Is this @model EditorForSample.Models.ProductViewModel namespace of View Model is correct ? also if your controller name FooController and Controller action FooAction in folder structure should have Views folder (from root) inside Views should have Foo Folder and if is default should have cshtml FooAction.cshtml

Comment: Yup. It works fine except when I add the radio button lines. Then all goes to pot.

Comment: refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518352/mvc4-two-radio-buttons-for-a-single-boolean-model-property

Comment: A 404 is a Not Found Error. It has nothing to do with your view. Somewhere your calling a method (perhaps a link) which does no exist.

Comment: I already read that answer. Doesn't help. The missing file is  /Views/Home/EditorTemplates/ProductViewModel.cshtml.

Comment: @JAbraham check this .netfiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/izYVGz there is nothing wrong with Radio buttons so check again

Answer (score 0):

You should send the viewmodel to the view like this.

```
ProductViewModel productViewModel= new ProductViewModel();

//populate productViewModel with values

View(productViewModel);
```

also make sure that you added the correct namespace at the top of your file

like this :

```
using Project.Models;
```

EDIT:

example for adding Radiobutton in view for same model property:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Selected, "false") 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Selected, "true")
```

In controller it should be like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return Content("IsFemale: " + model.Selected);
    }
```

I think this will inspire you. Of course you have to modify it according to the way you need.

Comment: I already do that. I can get it working fine except when I add the radio button lines. Then I suddenly get a 404 error even though it *appears* to be the correct syntax (although I'm not very good with HTML so not 100% sure). My question is about how I get the radio buttons, or how exactly I'm breaking the .cshtml when I try to add radio buttons.